# AWS Run Command Ignores First PowerShell Parameter - Outputs ; exit $LASTEXITCODE

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

I am running a PowerShell Script using AWS Run Command. I have a set of Parameters that I pass to my script. However, the first parameter returns the following instead of the value I declared:

```
; exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

Here is my snippet:

```
param(      
        [String] $param1 = 'abc', 
        [String] $param2 = 'dfg',         
        [String] $param3 = '123',
        [String] $param4 = '456'        
        )

Write-Output $param1
Write-Output $param2
Write-Output $param3
Write-Output $param4
```

I expect $param1 to output abc, but it returns ; exit $LASTEXITCODE

If I put $param4 or any other parameter to be first in order, it also returns ; exit $LASTEXITCODE

In essence, using AWS Run Command to execute PowerShell my first parameter is being ignored or overridden with ; exit $LASTEXITCODE

Running the code in a PowerShell ISE it works. It is only in AWE Run Command that the error is produced.

Why is this happening and how do I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

`$LastExitCode` is nothing but the return code of native applications.

`$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` only works for PowerShell cmdlets but doesn't work at all for EXEs.

using `try/catch` is more major way to capture any native error. In your case if you are run the same snippet in local ISE, it will give proper output without any issue.

Hope it helps in understanding in a better way.